# Delete specific entity in cloud datastore in nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-functions

I want to delete a specific entity given some properties such as username, password, etc.

The following (used to test if I can retrieve the entity) gives an infinite loop (in cloud functions) and prints an empty object.

```
 var query = datastore.createQuery('account')
            .filter('email', '=', req.body.email)
            .filter('token', '=', req.body.token)
            .filter('password', '=', req.body.password);

        datastore.runQuery(query)
            .then((results) => {
                console.log(results[0]);
                var response = JSON.stringify({
                    status: "error",
                    message: results[0]
                });
            })
```

So my question is:

How can I find the ID of an entity retreived using properties and why is my code, supposed to retrieve this entity, is giving an empty object (all filters match, at least they correspond to what I can see in cloud datastore)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   datastore.runQuery(query, function(error, entity) {
            if (error){

            } else {
                entityKey = entity[0][datastore.KEY];   <=== This gives you the key of the entity

            }
```

Source: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/datastore/1.1.0/datastore